# QtQuick: Creating menu from ListModel

Tags: menu, qtquick2, menubar, listmodel

i am new to the forum and i started designing several things in QtQuick.
I am still exploring and learning the basic stuff and i stumbled upon the following problem.
When i try to create a menu (menubar) from a ListModel using Listview, i simply dont get any menu at all.
Maybe i have still an misunderstanding about the principles and you can help me.
Here is my basic code:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
MenuBar{
  id: menuBarId

  ListModel{
  id: listModelMenuId
  ListElement {menuname: "Test1"}
  ListElement {menuname: "Test2"}

  }
  ListView{
  id: listViewMenuId
  model: listModelMenuId
  delegate: Menu {
          id: menu
          title: model.menuname
          Action { text: qsTr("Tool Bar"); checkable: true }
          Action { text: qsTr("Side Bar"); checkable: true; checked: true }
          Action { text: qsTr("Status Bar"); checkable: true; checked: true;}

          MenuSeparator {
              contentItem: Rectangle {
                  implicitWidth: 200
                  implicitHeight: 1
                  color: "#21be2b"
              }
          }
          Menu {
              title: qsTr("Advanced")
          }

          topPadding: 2
          bottomPadding: 2
//          delegate: mydelegateid

          background: Rectangle {
              implicitWidth: 200
              implicitHeight: 40
              color: "#ffffff"
              border.color: "#21be2b"
              radius: 2


          }
      }} }
```

I got my sample from the qt site and tampered with it by adding the ListModel. 
Also interesting is that if i want to refactor the original coding by using a component where i pack up the MenuItem and call the compoenent it also not works. Can it be that menus in general work different thand other Items? 
If i left something important out just tell me, i'll add more information.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the issue.
[Example to delegate your style in a MenuBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856207/how-to-change-the-font-color-of-a-menubar)

This resolved the problem in general. However, i still wonder why i can not encapsulate the MenuItem into a component and use the components id to delegate the style for the items....
Regards,
Seryoga